# Range of difference of $f$ and $g$ at $2/3$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous real valued functions on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$ such that $f(0)=g(0)=1$ and $\left| \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} \right| > 2 $ $\forall x \in (0,1)$. Then what is the range of $|f(2/3) - g(2/3)|$?

Tried using cauchy's MVT to get $|f(2/3) - 1| > 2 |g(2/3) - 1|$ but can't think of ways to proceed further.

Comment: have you learned Cauchy's Theorem (generealisation of Lagrange)

Comment: it'd be useful if you could pls share some reference/link for the theorem you are referring to

Comment: looking at pure-math problems after a long gap of 2.5 years, my calculus has become a bit rusty and unable to to recall all theorems.

Comment: See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy's_mean_value_theorem

Comment: okay cauchy MVT, I have used it but unable to proceed further, the last line of the question indicates the inequality I obtained after using cauchy mvt.

Comment: The only useful consequence of this inequality is that $f(2/3)\neq g(2/3)$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Consider the following example $f=1+\frac{9}{4}\alpha x$, $g=1+\frac{3}{4}\alpha x$ with $\alpha\neq 0$

Comment: Wow!! that's brilliant @IvanKaznacheyeu